# Is using repeatedly a function that outputs its arguments efficient?

Tags: performance-tuning, function-construction, evaluation, variable-definitions

I understand that the title of the question might seem a little confusing so I will try to present an example of the actual problem instance.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
f[args__, warg___] := Module[{i=1, x, v},

  While[

    b[args, i],

    x = h1[args];

    v = g[x, warg];

    h2[v];

    i++

   ]

 ]
```

For all intents and purposes, you may treat `h1` and `h2` as functions defined elsewhere (in effect, they are just a bunch of expressions defined in the body of `f`, *preceding* and *following* the evaluation of `g`). Also, `b` is just a boolean expression needed in `While`. It depends on input argument(s) and the value of a step counter `i`.

The function `f` (which is *more-or-less* the workhorse of my code) has a number of input parameters. The inputs are divided into two group.

The first group, denoted with `args__` in the code, consists of all those parameters needed in subsequent computations. 
The second group of inputs is denoted with `warg___` ('*w*' for '*wildcard*') and is actually a kind of *switch*.

When the `warg` parameter is present, function `g` executes and produces `v` (which is used in the rest of the code of `f` to produce the output). On the other hand, when the input argument `warg` is not present (the function `f` is called without it eg as in `f[args]`, no `warg` present), function `g`- essentially-outputs its inputs ie `x`. Below is the (pseudo-)code definition for `g`.

```
g[arg_, warg_] := Module[{} 

  h3[arg, warg]      

 ]

g[arg_] := arg
```

(Similarly, `h3` is a shorthand for the body of `g`).

***Now, where's the rub?***

Well, the thing is that, although `g` is not *expensive* in terms of amount of computations performed, especially when it simply acts as a *relay* or an `Identity` transformation (spitting out `x` in the absence of `warg`), function `f` gets called ***a lot*** and `g` gets called that much more often (note how `g` is in a `While` loop in `f`).

So, I guess, the question is, if writing two separate versions of `f` (one including `g` and one simply calling `h2[x]` instead of `v = g[x, warg]` and then `h2[v]` in the case where `warg` is absent) would be more *efficient* than the current arrangement of using `warg` as a *switch* (and having the main loop try two different `g`'s on for size every time). Obviously, in that former case, I would not need to have two definitions for `g`. Namely, the `Identity` transformation `g[arg] := arg` would not have a reason for being.

Having written down this question, and after some contemplation, I tend to favor the later approach (two `f`'s, one `g`) for the simple reason that having the main loop decide which `f` to use ***many times*** is less expensive than doing the same thing for ***a lot more often*** with `g`, but I'd like to have a second opinion of more knowledgeable users.

As a post-script, please bear in mind that 'obsessing' over *efficiency* has to do with the fact that I'd like to port this code into a `Manipulate` at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do a quick test:

```
ClearAll[g, h]
g[arg_, warg_] := h[arg, warg]
g[arg_] := arg

ClearAll[f1, f2]
f1[arg_, warg___] := g[arg, warg]
f2[arg_] := arg

10^# & /@ Range[5, 6];
% // AssociationMap@Function[{n},
   First@Timing[# /@ Range[n]] & /@ {f1, f2}
   ]
```

> ```
> <|100 000 -> {1.04688, 0.421875}, 1 000 000 -> {9.375, 3.29688}|>
> ```

(For the purposes of the test I stripped away all but the two different types of `f`'s and `g`'s.)

It seems the first method is a factor of roughly 2 or 3 slower.

Unfortunately there's tension between writing code that looks the nicest (and uses the full power of *Mathematica*) versus code that performs best.  Luckily, at least in this case, it's not *too* bad, so you can often get away with using the more aesthetically pleasing code.

Comment: I thought so too; your assertion is spot on.

Comment: Thanks for the accept, but (following others around here) I like to encourage OP's to wait ~24 hours before accepting an answer, to encourage others to look at the question and likely give a better answer.

Comment: I doubt anyone else is actively interested but I'll be the last one to break from tradition so I'll revoke it-for now; thanks!